# How to Update CSV file not to Insert new Items using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, streamreader, streamwriter

I want to Update row of CSV file I tried but I only found append which adds new row. where as I need to update row not to insert new row.

Here is data in my csv file

**EnjoyBaseHid=hid://002AB1E3,MinID=1,MaxID=900
EnjoyBaseHid=hid://005AC1D4,MinID=1,MaxID=600**

I want to update according to EnjoyBaseHid

```
While Not sr.EndOfStream
                            Dim line = sr.ReadLine()
                            Dim values() As String = line.Split(",")
                            If values(0).Equals("EnjoyBaseHid=" & portAddress) Then
                                Nobasefound = False
                                line = line.Replace(values(1), "MinID=" & minID)
                                line = line.Replace(values(2), "MaxID=" & maxID)
                                sr.Close()
                                Dim strWrite As New IO.StreamWriter(ExportListPathString, False)
                                strWrite.WriteLine(line)
                                strWrite.Close()
                                Exit While
                            End If
End While
```

This overwrites all file and the result is

**EnjoyBaseHid=hid://005AC1D4,MinID=1,MaxID=1000**

When I change following line

```
Dim strWrite As New IO.StreamWriter(ExportListPathString, False)
```

To this

```
Dim strWrite As New IO.StreamWriter(ExportListPathString, True)
```

It appends new line and result is following

```
EnjoyBaseHid=hid://002AB1E3,MinID=1,MaxID=900
EnjoyBaseHid=hid://005AC1D4,MinID=1,MaxID=600
EnjoyBaseHid=hid://005AC1D4,MinID=1,MaxID=1000
```

But I need this

EnjoyBaseHid=hid://002AB1E3,MinID=1,MaxID=900
EnjoyBaseHid=hid://005AC1D4,MinID=1,MaxID=1000

Comment: How about two streams. A reader and a writer. Write each line from your source file until you reach the point where you want to insert your new line. Then write the new line. The finish off by writing the rest of the lines from the source file.

Comment: I am using both stream wreiter and reader sr is stream reader and strwrite is stream writer and I don't want to insert new line I just want to update line existing in file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the idea I had in mind.

```
Private Sub fileHandler(sourceFile As String, portAddress As String, newMin As String, newMax As String)

    Dim tempOutFileName As String = String.Concat(sourceFile, "_tmp")
    Dim oldFileName As String = String.Concat(sourceFile, "_old")

    'clear away temp file
    If File.Exists(tempOutFileName) Then
        File.Delete(tempOutFileName)
    End If

    'clear away old file
    If File.Exists(oldFileName) Then
        File.Delete(oldFileName)
    End If

    'open writer for new temp file
    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(tempOutFileName, True)
        'open reader for source file
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(sourceFile)
            Do While sr.Peek <> -1
                Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine
                'check if the line read is the one you want to change
                If line.Contains(portAddress) Then
                    'write your NEW line
                    sw.WriteLine(String.Concat(portAddress, "-", newMin, "-", newMax))
                Else
                    'write the existing line without changes
                    sw.WriteLine(line)
                End If
            Loop
            sr.Close()
        End Using
        sw.Close()
    End Using

    'backup source to old
    File.Move(sourceFile, oldFileName)
    'move temp to source
    File.Move(tempOutFileName, sourceFile)

End Sub
```